# Div in screen center when there are frames?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I place a div into the SCREEN (not page) center, 
when the div is in an iframe, 
and the div's x position for being in the SCREEN center is 
too far left for still being on the iframe page (div.x < iFramePage.x) ?

The iframe is in a table in the right row, and in the left row there is a navigation treeview.

Now my div should overlap the treeview, for being in the center...

How can I do that ?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the 'float' property in CSS. I am not sure if it can be used withinin frames - hence the comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.** The contents of an iframe will never be able to "leave" the frame, instead, the iframe will get scrollbars.

No offense, but this sounds like a poor site architecture anyways. Maybe you should have a look at (lightweight) content management systems. Having that said, maybe you have a very very grace reason for this "architecture"?

Comment: Maybe Microsoft should just fix the bugs in their rendering engine, then I wouldn't need an iframe. Firefox and Chrome would work, but not IE.

I've found a solution non-the less: place the div on the parent page with display: none or visibility: hidden, and make it visible via javascript from the iframe ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That would defy the point of an iframe. And it could also be used to display ads outside of the box in which they paid to be displayed. And nobody wants that, do they...

Answer (score 1):

As Mef and Valamo answerd, it's **not** possible to align the `div` in center of the page which is inside an `iframe`. Instead of doing this, you can consider moving the `div` to the parent document (which contains the `iframe`) and you can align the `div` as you want.